# Show/hide table rows based on dynamic content in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an HTML table as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-show="showCats"><td>Cat</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showDogs"><td>Dog</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showCats"><td>Cat</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showDogs"><td>Dog</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showCats"><td>Cat</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showLizards"><td>Lizard</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showLizards"><td>Lizard</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showMice"><td>Mouse</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showMice"><td>Mouse</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="showDogs"><td>Dog</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

And links as follows:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="showRows('all')">Show all</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="showRows('cats')">Cats</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="showRows('dogs')">Dogs</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="showRows('lizards')">Lizards</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="showRows('mice')">Mice</a>
```

What's the proper way in Angular to hide/show each row when an animal type is clicked? I'm aware of [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter), but I'm under the impression that that only works for tables generated in Angular using `ng-repeat`. (This table is being generated server-side.)

I have a working solution that manually sets each `showAnimal` variable to true/false based on what was clicked, but this seems like an inefficient, unscalable approach. Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't this be easier if you only generate a JSON corresponding to your table on server side ? This way you could easily use ng-repeat and filter, and it would be scalable, and quite efficient

Comment: I've went ahead and written a detailed blog post about [hiding and showing elements in AngularJS](http://www.andrewboni.com/2013/08/25/show-and-hide-elements-with-angularjs/). Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

Given your constraints, you could do something like this: [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tWwYd9ju2js6s8XkOTnA?p=preview)

Controller

```
$scope.selected = 'all';
$scope.isShown = function(animal) {
  if ($scope.selected == 'all') {
    return true;
  }
  return $scope.selected == animal;
}
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="selected">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="lizard">Lizard</option>
  <option value="mice">Mice</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('cat')"><td>Cat</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('dog')"><td>Dog</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('cat')"><td>Cat</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('dog')"><td>Dog</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('cat')"><td>Cat</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('lizard')"><td>Lizard</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('lizard')"><td>Lizard</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('mice')"><td>Mouse</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('mice')"><td>Mouse</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr ng-show="isShown('dog')"><td>Dog</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```